# Is it possible for me to do the performance testing in localhost with actual network environment?

Tags: performance, testing, localhost, bandwidth, traffic

I need to test the performance of application running on localhost as if it were in the online environment. I mean the performance test conducted by the network traffic simulation, limited bandwidth simulation, or other parameter as if it were online.

Could Apache Ab do the simulation?

Answer (score 5):

We've used [Charles](http://www.charlesproxy.com/) and [Firefox Throttle](http://www.uselessapplications.com/en/Application/FirefoxThrottle.aspx) in the past to simulate slow networks.

Answer (score 0):

Why can't you connect to a different PC, or even use a virtual machine and rate limit the virtual network connection?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, but you will need to connect to your application by IP address, not "localhost" or 127.0.0.1.  Typically for web applications (HTTP) I use Fiddler which can simulate limited bandwidth, but only if you connect as I have noted.  Other bandwidth limiters for non-HTTP I'm not sure/aware of.

Answer (score 0):

Ab won't simulate low level network errors. If you're on linux, you can simulate some networking with 'tc'. See http://www.kdedevelopers.org/node/1878 for a small example.

Answer (score 0):

You can set up a local tunnel to expose your localhost to the world, using [Ngrok](https://ngrok.com/). From there you can use any number of online performance tools

You can [throttle bandwidth via Chrome Dev Tools](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/network-performance/network-conditions)