# How to limit connection speed of Zend server?

Tags: php, zend-framework

I want the Zend framework installed on localhost to behave as if it is on internet, for debugging purposes. there is a related post [Is it possible for me to do the performance testing in localhost with actual network environment?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2135551/is-it-possible-for-me-to-do-the-performance-testing-in-localhost-with-actual-net) but I wonder if there is a specific solution for/in Zend?

Comment: Why do you want something specific to Zend instead of using one of the excellent server agnostic options given as answers to that question?

Comment: Charles is not free and Firefox Throttle is not working for firefox12. fiddler is causing my connection to hang after a while.